# Insert or update a document in ArangoDB fails with constraint violated

Tags: arangodb

I would like to achieve an Upsert in ArangoDB, but I can't get it working with the examples provided in the documentation of [create-document](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/HTTP/Document/WorkingWithDocuments.html#create-document). My requests fail with a `unique constraint violated` error message.

I'm inserting a document with a specific `_key` in a collection, and the `overwrite` option set to `true` as described in the documentation, but I still get the error messages. Here's the results of the described curl calls on my environment.

**call #1:**

```
curl -X POST --header 'accept: application/json'\
             --data-binary @- --dump - \
             http://localhost:8529/_api/document/products\?overwrite\=true \
<<EOF
{ "Hello": "Universe", "_key" : "lock" }
EOF
```

**response #1:**

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: /_db/_system/_api/document/products/lock
Etag: "_X28xHz---_"
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58  

{"_id":"products/lock","_key":"lock","_rev":"_X28xHz---_"}
```

**call #2:** *(identique to the first one)*

```
curl -X POST --header 'accept: application/json'\
             --data-binary @- --dump - \
             http://localhost:8529/_api/document/products\?overwrite\=true \
<<EOF
{ "Hello": "Universe", "_key" : "lock" }
EOF
```

**response #2:**

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 153

{"error":true,"errorMessage":"unique constraint violated - in index 0 of type primary over [\"_key\"]; conflicting key: lock","code":409,"errorNum":1210}
```

I went through the documentation, I enabled and reviewed the server logs but I can't figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

Just in case, if this can be of any help, I run ArangoDB server locally with Docker with the following docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: arangodb
    ports:
    - "8529:8529"
    environment:
      ARANGO_NO_AUTH: 1
    volumes:
      - ./arangodb3:/var/lib/arangodb3
    command: "--log.level startup=trace --log.level requests=trace --log.level info"
```

And here's the log from the server:

```
db_1  | 2018-12-09T08:56:16Z [1] DEBUG {requests} "http-request-begin","0x7f51ac946010","172.20.0.1","POST","HTTP/1.1","/_api/document/products?overwrite=true"
db_1  | 2018-12-09T08:56:16Z [1] TRACE {requests} "http-request-body","0x7f51ac946010","{ \"Hello\": \"Universe\", \"_key\" : \"lock\" }\n"
db_1  | 2018-12-09T08:56:16Z [1] TRACE {requests} "http-request-response","0x7f51ac946010","/_api/document/products?overwrite=true","HTTP\/1.1 409 Conflict\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nServer: ArangoDB\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Type: application\/json; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 153\r\n\r\n{\"error\":true,\"errorMessage\":\"unique constraint violated - in index 0 of type primary over [\\\"_key\\\"]; conflicting key: lock\",\"code\":409,\"errorNum\":1210}"
db_1  | 2018-12-09T08:56:16Z [1] TRACE {requests} "http-request-statistics","0x7f51ac946010","172.20.0.1","POST","HTTP/1.1",409,41,153,"/_api/document/products?overwrite=true",read,0.000124931,queue,0.000000000,queue-size,0,request,0.000008106,total,0.017638445,error,false
db_1  | 2018-12-09T08:56:16Z [1] INFO {requests} "http-request-end","0x7f51ac946010","172.20.0.1","POST","HTTP/1.1",409,41,153,"/_api/document/products?overwrite=true",0.017630
```

Comment: For reference, at the time of writing the version of ArangoDB pulled by docker as `latest` was `3.3.20`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question on the slack channel of the ArangoDB community, and the fine people there pointed to me that the replace-insert via the overwrite parameter was introduced only since in `3.4`. Based on my docker compose, my image was pointing the the latest image of the [Official Docker Repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/arangodb/tags/) for *arangodb*, which is `3.3.20`.

I was explained that this "official" repository (`arangodb`) is not necessarily hosting the latest stable version of ArangoDB, and it can take days before it gets available, and I should instead point to `arangodb/arangodb`.

I adapted my `docker-compose.yml` file to use the right image, and now it works fine.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: arangodb/arangodb:3.4.0
    ports:
    - "8529:8529"
    environment:
      ARANGO_NO_AUTH: 1
    volumes:
      - ./arangodb3:/var/lib/arangodb3
```

Thank you again to the ArangoDB Community on Slack, and more particularly to @mpoeter!

Comment: You can accept your answer to indicate the question as solved. Thanks!